# How to downgrade Autorest extensions - specifically C# extension?

Tags: c#, rest, autorest

I am using Autorest to generate C# code from an OpenAPI YAML file. I tried to upgrade the Autorest C# extension to the newest version (3.0.0 beta), but I decided I don't want to use this version. Now I cannot figure out how to downgrade.

Ideally I want to run the same versions of Autorest and its extensions as my colleague here:

- autorest 3.1.3
- @autorest/core 3.0.6320
- @microsoft.azure/autorest.core 2.0.4417
- @microsoft.azure/autorest.csharp 2.3.91
- @microsoft.azure/autorest.modeller 2.3.55

But I'll be content just to downgrade the C# extension to 2.3.91, or just any 2.x version.

I cannot find any command to do this. Can anyone help?

**EDIT**: I am running Autorest from a command line. I have Autorest installed as a stand-alone tool on my machine. It is *not* installed as a NuGet Package or anything like that. The comments seems to suggest that it is possible to control the Autorest version via configuration when running it. I would also appreciate a reference to documentation explaining how to do this.

Comment: _"I cannot find any command"_ Does that mean you are trying this from the console?

Comment: nuget.exe: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-nuget-cli#install-a-specific-version-of-a-package

Comment: dotnet cli: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-dotnet-cli#install-a-specific-version-of-a-package

Comment: Why not just git revert your changes?   You are using GIT aren't you (if not, you should do).

Comment: @Neil: I have Autorest installed as a stand-alone tool on my machine. There is nothing in my source code that controls the Autorest version. If it is possible to control the Autorest version and extension versions when running it, could you please link me to a document showing how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding the following to my command line arguments:

```
--version=3.0.6320 --use=@microsoft.azure/autorest.csharp@2.3.91
```

Previously my command line had no version specified, so it would just use the newest version installed on the local machine. That, of course, was a recipe for machine-dependent disaster.

Thanks to the Autorest GitHub for the answer: https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/4342